# How i do Mock Test for my logout controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito

I want to create a Spring Boot test for my controller, but I dont know how.
Here is my Code:

Controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = Constants.LOGOUT_URL)
public String logout (HttpServletRequest request) throws ApiException {

    String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (authHeader != null) {
        try {
            String tokenValue = authHeader.replace("Bearer", "").trim();
            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(tokenValue);
            tokenStore.removeAccessToken(accessToken);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.toString();
        }
    }
    return Utils.convertDateTime();
}
```

This is my test, this take me a NullPointerException:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureRestDocs
public class AuthControllerTest {

    @Rule
    public JUnitRestDocumentation jUnitRestDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation();

    @InjectMocks
    private AuthController controller = new AuthController();

    // To be initialised in the setup method.
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private AuthService service;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)
            .apply(documentationConfiguration(this.jUnitRestDocumentation))
            .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void getLogout() throws Exception, ApiException {

        String result = "{\"date\":\"20190212:0000\"}";

       HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
       when(request.getHeader("principal")).thenReturn("admin");
       when(request.getHeader("authorization")).thenReturn("authtoken");
       when(controller.logout(any(request.getClass()))).thenReturn(result);

    }
}
```

I dont know how make the test for the Logout Controller

The exception I get is the following:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sodexo.oneapp.api.auth.AuthController.login(AuthController.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: show us what you tried and what problems exactly have you encoutered

Comment: Well, when i try the construct the test, the process take me a NullPointerException, maybe is because the method receive an HttpServletRequest object ?

Comment: I dont know how pass the object into the Mock Test

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at com.sodexo.oneapp.api.auth.AuthController.login(AuthController.java:35)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

Comment: show us the test class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Rest Assured to test the Controller quite easy. Here is the documation: https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage

The test could look something like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
class MyControllerTest {

@Mock
private MyService myService;

@InjectMocks
private MyController MyController;

@Before
public static void init(){
    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost";
    RestAssured.port = 8080;
}

@Test
void givenUrl_whenSuccessOnGetLogoutAndStuff_thenCorrect() {

    when(this.myService.getLogout(stuff)).thenReturn(something);

    given()
        .standaloneSetup(new MyController(this.myService))
        .header("principal", "admin")
        .header("authorization", "authtoken")
    .when()
        .get("/logout")
    .then()
        .statusCode(200)
        .statusLine("...")
        .body(something);
    }

}
```

Make sure to use the MockMvc module of Rest Assured:

```
import static io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc.*;
```

Comment: How i add the asciiDoc ?  like this .andDo(document("user",requestFields(fieldWithPath("user").description("text")